# Searching a value between two columns on a reference sheet

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I have my main sheet that looks like this:

[image: Main Sheet]

The `Compromise` column (`Column F`) bases its value on another sheet. To compute its value, we check if the value of the `Basic Tax` (`Column B`) falls equal or between the first two columns of the reference sheet:

[image: Reference Sheet]

I can actually perform a simple `VLOOKUP()` function, but how can I implement that referencing to a range instead of a singe column?

How can I derive the value for the `Compromise` column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`vlookup`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) is exactly the right tool here. With `is_sorted` set to TRUE, it finds the largest number that is less than or equal to the search key. Specifically, the formula

```
=vlookup(B2, ReferenceSheet!A$4:C, 3, True)
```

returns the 3rd column entry of the range (`ReferenceSheet!A$4:C`) namely the value in C column.

The only issue here is the equality case. If the search key is exactly 500.00, then vlookup will match row 5 and return 400, which is not what you want. (This would not be a problem if the lower end of every range was inclusive, which is often the case in tax tables).

There are two solutions for the equality case issue:

1. Subtract 0.01 (or 0.0000001) from the basic tax value prior to comparison, to bump the borderline case to the previous bracket. That is, do `=vlookup(B2-0.01, ReferenceSheet!A$4:C, 3, True)`
2. Change the tax table so that the lower end of every range is inclusive.